# Oracle ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended?

Tags: sql, eclipse, oracle, sql-update, ora-00933

I keep getting this error.
How do I solve this problem?

**Error**:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

**Code**:

```
<update id="updateProc" parameterClass="rating">
 update rating set
 rating_title=#rating_title#
 rating_cont=#rating_cont#
 where mem_id=#mem_id# 
 and rating_code=#rating_code#         
</update>
```

Comment: Please mention the sql query you are executing

Comment: think about it, your query is not properly ended...

Answer (score 4):

Please put `,` between your columns of `Set` Clause like:

```
update rating set rating_title=#rating_title#, rating_cont=#rating_cont#
where mem_id=#mem_id# and rating_code=#rating_code#
```

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, string literals are denoted by single quotes (`'`). So, if you plan to use literals:

```
UPDATE rating 
SET    rating_title='rating_title', rating_cont='rating_cont' 
WHERE  mem_id='mem_id' AND rating_code='rating_code'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this exact same error if you have quotes that are not properly closed or you forget to use double quotes inside of a statement with single quotes on the outside.